# Matching a complete complex nested collection item instead of separate members with Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have an index with a nested collection of items I want to hit. A collection item contains multiple properties that all have to match a certain query, not just any of them. Here's the model:

```cs
public class IndexEntry1
{
    public IEnumerable<NestedType1> NestedProperty1 { get; set; }
}

public class NestedType1
{
    public string Member1 { get; set; }
    public string Member2 { get; set; }
}
```

So I want to hit only documents that have a specific combination of `Member1` and `Member2` values in the `IndexEntry1.NestedProperty1` collection.

I figured that I had to map the collection as nested.

Here's the mapping:

```
index: {
    properties: {
        nestedProperty1: {
            type: "nested",
            properties: {
                member1: {
                    type: "string",
                    index_analyzer: "my_index_analyzer_1",
                    search_analyzer: "my_search_analyzer_1"
                },
                member2: {
                    type: "string",
                    analyzer: "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    analysis: {
        tokenizer: {
            my_ngram: {
                type: "nGram",
                min_gram: "1",
                max_gram: "15"
            }
        },
        analyzer: {
            my_index_analyzer_1: {
                type: "custom",
                tokenizer: "my_ngram",
                filters: ["lowercase"]
            },
            my_search_analyzer_1: {
                type: "custom",
                tokenizer: "whitespace",
                filters: ["lowercase"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and use a query like this:

```cs
client.Search<IndexEntry1>(d => d
    .Query(query => query
        .Nested(n => n
            .Path(p => p.NestedProperty1)
                .Query(q => q
                    .Bool(b => b
                        .Must(
                            m => m.Term("member1", "value1"),
                            m => m.QueryString(s => s.OnField("member2")
                                .Query("value2"))))))));
```

However, I'm still getting hits on any document that has either the `value1` value or the `value2` value while I expect only hits on documents with both values on the same `NestedProperty1` collection item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that it should only find documents where the nested document has value1 AND value2.

You can observe this is how elasticsearch behaves by running the following in [sense (chrome plugin)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sense/doinijnbnggojdlcjifpdckfokbbfpbo?hl=en):

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/nested_example
{
    "mappings": {
        "indexentry" : {
            "properties": {
                "nestedCollection": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "prop1" : { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                        "prop2" : { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
POST http://localhost:9200/nested_example/indexentry/1
{
    "nestedCollection": [
        { "prop1" : "A", "prop2" : "A" },
        { "prop1" : "B", "prop2" : "B" }
    ]
}
POST http://localhost:9200/nested_example/indexentry/2
{
    "nestedCollection": [
        { "prop1" : "C", "prop2" : "C" },
        { "prop1" : "D", "prop2" : "D" }
    ]
}

POST http://localhost:9200/nested_example/indexentry/_search
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
           "path": "nestedCollection",
           "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                       {
                           "term": {
                              "nestedCollection.prop1": {
                                 "value": "A"
                              }
                           }
                       },
                       {
                           "term": {
                              "nestedCollection.prop2": {
                                 "value": "A"
                              }
                           }
                       }

                    ]
                }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

The previous query will only find document `1` but as soon as you change the term query for `nestedColleciton.prop2` to find `B` instead of `A` you will no longer get any response as expected.

If I update the example to be more true to your mappings and queries I cannot reproduce the behaviour your witnessing:

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/nested_example
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "tokenizer": {
            "my_ngram": {
               "type": "nGram",
               "min_gram": "1",
               "max_gram": "15"
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "my_index_analyzer_1": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "my_ngram",
               "filters": [
                  "lowercase"
               ]
            },
            "my_search_analyzer_1": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filters": [
                  "lowercase"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "indexentry": {
         "properties": {
            "nestedCollection": {
               "type": "nested",
               "properties": {
                  "prop1": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "index_analyzer": "my_index_analyzer_1",
                     "search_analyzer": "my_search_analyzer_1"
                  },
                  "prop2": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "analyzer": "keyword"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
POST http://localhost:9200/nested_example/indexentry/1
{
    "nestedCollection": [
        { "prop1" : "value1", "prop2" : "value1" },
        { "prop1" : "value2", "prop2" : "value2" }
    ]
}
POST http://localhost:9200/nested_example/indexentry/2
{
    "nestedCollection": [
        { "prop1" : "value3", "prop2" : "value3" },
        { "prop1" : "value4", "prop2" : "value4" }
    ]
}

POST http://localhost:9200/nested_example/indexentry/_search
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
           "path": "nestedCollection",
           "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                       {
                           "term": {
                              "prop1": {
                                 "value": "value1"
                              }
                           }
                       },
                       {
                           "query_string": {
                               "fields": [
                                  "prop2"
                               ],
                               "query": "value1"

                           }
                       }

                    ]
                }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Can you update the previous example to better reproduce your situation?

Final note in NEST you can rewrite the query as:

```cs
client.Search<IndexEntry1>(d => d
    .Query(query => query
        .Nested(n => n
            .Path(p => p.NestedProperty1)
            .Query(q => 
                q.Term(p => p.NestedProperty1.First().Member1, "value1")
                && q.QueryString(s => s
                    .OnField(p => p.NestedPropery1.First().Member2)
                    .Query("value2")
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Strongly typed and with less nesting going on.

Comment: Thanks! Replacing my query by yours simply did the trick. Don't know what was actually going on. I really should enable trace logging in NEST to inspect the HTTP traffic.