# How to do a nested query into an array of objects

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I have a simple object with a nested array of objects

```
public class Product {
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ProductTag[] Tags {get; set;} = new ProductTag[0];

}
public class ProductTag {
    public string TagName {get; set;}
    public string Color {get; set;} = "orange";
}
```

Where `Tags` is [mapped as a nested datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) using

```
client.CreateIndex(Indices.Index<Product>(), d =>
   d.Mappings(m =>
      m.Map<Product>(mm => mm
        .AutoMap()
        .Properties(pd => pd
            .Text(tpd => tpd.Name(x => x.Name))
            .Nested<ProductTag>(npd => npd
                .Name(x => x.Tags)
                .AutoMap()
                .Properties(pd2 => pd2
                  .Keyword(kpd => kpd
                    .Name(x => x.Color)
                  )
                )
            )
        )
      )
   )
```

I can't for the life of me however figure out how to query the product index for all products which for example have a tag with a `TagName` of "orange".

I managed to get this far and then I don't know

```
client.Search<Product>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
       .Nested(nqd => nqd
        .Path(x => x.Tags)
        .Query(qcd => qcd
            .Bool(bqd => bqd
                .Must(qcd
                    .Match(mqd => mqd
                        .??? 
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Since `Nested` seems to not set another type to query against I'm a bit lost as to how to do this query.

Comment: Try mqd.Tags.TagName,"orange"

Comment: @sramalingam24 this is c# using nested closure pattern so it is strongly typed. That wouldn't compile

Comment: Oops forgot a .First() there. See here for a similar example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800533/elasticsearch-nest-filtering-on-multilevel-nested-types

Comment: @sramalingam24 yes! that did it (also just `.Field("tags.tagName").Query("admiral")` seems to work - I didn't think to try it until I read their docs about how they use implicit conversion operators. Want to make an answer out of your response and I'll mark it correct?

Comment: glad you found it useful, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will do it

```
client.Search<Product>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Nested(nqd => nqd
            .Path(x => x.Tags)
            .Query(qcd => qcd
                .Match(mqd => mqd
                    .Field(f => f.Tags.First().TagName)
                    .Query("orange")
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

which generates

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "tags.tagName": {
            "query": "orange"
          }
        }
      },
      "path": "tags"
    }
  }
}
```

The lambda expression to get the name of the field is simply that, an expression. NEST understands that the LINQ method `.First()` in this context is part of an expression to traverse to the target field. You could also use any of

```
f => f.Tags[0].TagName
f => f.Tags.Last().TagName
f => f.Tags.Single().TagName
f => f.Tags.ElementAt(0).TagName
f => f.Tags.Max().TagName
```

or any other LINQ expression that would return a `ProductTag` on which a property can be accessed, and that represents a `MemberExpression`

Answer (score 1):

Try mqd.Tags.First().TagName,"admiral"